# Can I write an app that is neither a source nor a sink?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to use Spring Cloud Data Flow server to manage all my application. Also, I'm new to everything spring.

I want to write an application that reads files from SFTP and write them to S3. The files can be very big (~ 500MB each), which can be very heave to pass as a message payload. Since all I do is read from SFTP and write to S3 I thought I could avoid a broker by having a single application read file from SFTP to a local file then upload the local file to S3, or even better, stream the bytes directly from SFTP to S3.

I'm at lost on how to start creating such an application.

Answer (score 1):

Well, couple of things here

1. What you're describing is the app which is both *Source* and *Sink* or in other words *Processor* (another stereotype which simply encapsulates Source and Sink).
2. Spring Cloud Stream supports [Spring Integration](https://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) configuration to implement complex flows and/or rely utilize pre-made adapters/connectors. 
   One of such adapters is [streaming](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-streaming) SFTP adapter which essentially allows you to stream data from SFTP instead of reading it into memory.

So essentially you can accomplish exactly what you want using existing components provided by Spring Integration.

Please look through the docs and see if if it makes sense and let us know if you need more help.

Comment: I would say this is Spring Cloud Task based on Spring Integration Channel Adapters.

Comment: @oleg-zhurakousky why is my app a processor? The way I see it it's neither a source nor a sink. A processor is both a source and a sink and so it binds to a broker to receive messages and to a broker to send messages. I don't want to receive or send messages and I don't want to bind to a broker

Comment: Well. . . what I was trying to explain is that in general context of Spring Cloud Stream it's an app that has a Source (input, SFTP) and Sink (output, S3) hence a Processor. That said, I do see and agree with your point. In fact I'll go further and state that all you need is a simple Spring-Integration wired Spring Boot app (not Spring Cloud Stream app) essentially using Spring Integration and its adapters to do what you need to do.